# How to remove the order in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to reset the "sidx" and "sord" parameters in a jqgrid when it is displayed for the first time? I mean, I have a jqgrid that loads the data in the server side, this jqgrid is in a hidden div and I want every time that the div is displayed the ordering was by default (despite of user changes).

If tried to set the "sord" and "sidx" to empty from the JSP in the request with no success due to when arrives to the server remains the user ordering.

```
    <%=request.setAttribute("sidx", "CODE");%>
    <%=request.setAttribute("sord", "asc");%>
```

I think that maybe the key is using the setGridParam when my div is displayed, but when I do that I can see my jqgrid with no order (yeah!) but the columns header remains the ordering and when I try to order again the jqgrid do nothing , it's broken :(

```
$("#${myGrid}").setGridParam({
        url: "${param.urlBase}/search.do",
        postData: {},
        page: 1,
        sidx: "",
        sord: "",
        sortname: "",
        sortorder: ""
    }).trigger("reloadGrid")
```

Any ideas?

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you create jqGrid **without** `sortname` parameter then the default value (`sortname: ""`) will be used. No sorting icons should exist in the column headers (if you don't use some old and buggy version of jqGrid). The exact answer on your question depends on the version of jqGrid and the fork which you use. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop, supports for example `threeStateSort: true` option, which allows the user to return the grid in *unsorted* (original) state in the order returned from the server.

Comment: I'm using the jqGrid 4.5.4 version...

Comment: jqGrid 4.5.4 is **very old**. It's dead. I remind me about the bug with displaying sort icons even in case of usage `sortname: ""` (I think that the problem was only if no `rownumbers: true` was used). The bug is fixed since a long time.